# Building Python in ST3

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimerepl

I am new to using Python and currently have version 3.4 installed on my Mac and Windows PC. I've been using it for a week or so in class and I am super tired of IDLE, so I have been trying to set up a dev environment in a program I used a lot for the web development I used to do: Sublime Text.

So, I have all my plug-ins set up and my Windows PC has a plugin called SublimeREPL (from Wuub, it's really nice) but it doesn't quite work as well for me on my Mac, so I was just going to create a "Build" file to use CMD + B with to run any code I was working on - kinda like a built in Shell or something.

Right now, my build is this

```
{
"cmd": ["/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

and when I run any .py file I get this:

```
Todo
Enter your first name: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rileybarnett/Dropbox/Purdue CS/CS177/Project0/project0.py", line 37, in <module>
main()
  File "/Users/rileybarnett/Dropbox/Purdue CS/CS177/Project0/project0.py", line 5, in main
first = input("Enter your first name: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd:['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4', '-u', '/Users/rileybarnett/Dropbox/Purdue CS/CS177/Project0/project0.py']]
[dir: /Users/rileybarnett/Dropbox/purdue cs/cs177/project0]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

I am not really sure what to do? That seems to be the correct path. Also: when I use "Automatic" to try to build for Python ST3 seems to be able to do little things like "print("Hello World")" correctly, but it gives me a similar message for any actual function written in Python.

Is there a better way to be doing this? Should I just download a real IDE? Any tips are appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What do you mean SublimeREPL isn't working on your Mac? Also, it's been quite well documented on SO and other places that you can't use `input()` or other languages' equivalents in Sublime.

Comment: @MattDMo On my windows PC SublimeREPL will just open up in my second column and run whatever I ask it too, it works pretty well. It's not doing the same on my Mac, I'll keep working with it though.  EDIT: As for    Input( ) not working on Sublime text, I wasn't aware, thanks.